# MATLAB if-else statement

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write an if-else statement that sets a value of an array to 0.1 at n=0 because the equation that computes that array has undetermined value at that input. The equation is:

[image]

So at 0 the value is infinity.

This is the code I wrote but it doesn't seem to work:

```matlab
n = -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2;
hlp = (1./n*pi).*(sin(0.1*pi.*n));

if n == 0
    hlp = 0.1;
else
    hlp = (1./n*pi).*(sin(0.1*pi.*n));
end
```

Comment: For refference, the issue you have in your code is that its not a loop, so `n` is never `n==0`, as `n = -(N-1)/2:(N-1)/2;`. Your code would work with a couple of changes: make a for loop `for ii=n`, and then access each variable per value ( `n(ii)` and `hlp(ii)`). That is what is flawed in your logic. The one liner solution is better, but sometimes you can't avoid loops.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are close. See if this works.

```
n = ( -(N-1)/2  ):(  (N-1)/2  );    %add some parentheses here
hlp = (1./n*pi).*(sin(0.1*pi.*n));  %this line is unchanged
```

When working on a subset of a vector, if/else
isn't really the right construct. Try this instead.

```
%create a mask of the elements to replace
maskN0 = (n==0)
%then replace them
hlp(maskN0) = 0.1;
```

OR, after you've been doing this a while, it may be
more natural to write  (Thanks Ander Biguri)

```
hlp(n==0) = 0.1;
%When I read this, I hear: "hlp, where n=0, set to 0.1"
```

Comment: Are you sure help() will replace it? Because help in MATLAB is used to explain what the function does.

Comment: There was a critical.typo. `help` instead of `hlp`. Updated

Comment: You can even shorten this to `hlp(n==0)=0.1;` which makes it more readable, imho.